# Properties inheritance?

Tags: java, spring

Is there anyway to do inheritance of properties?
 This would be good in different regions specific property environment .

Like
Common.properties
Abc=myvalue

Developer specific environment 
Local.properties
FileLocation=xyz1

Dev cloud environment
Dev.properties
FileLocation=xyz2

QA cloud environment
QA.properties
FileLocation=xyz2

Prod cloud environment 
prod.properties
FileLocation=xyz3

Like above in common.properties will have all common properties others will region specific

I know in spring we can do using profile base but still..we have to include both properties in each region.
If there is such tool or configuration in spring, really it would be good know n use it.

Comment: Have you looked at the [`Properties` constructor that accepts default `Properties` as parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#Properties%28java.util.Properties%29)?

Answer (score 0):

A pattern I've used (and see other's use it too) for a long time while using spring is the following.

Have a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` that loads files in the following order

1. common.properties
2. ${env}.properties

The ${env}.properties will override any properties with the same key in common.properties.

when you launch your application, you'll need to tell it which on which environment you're running, and then spring will inject whatever properties you need in your beans.

I hope I'm answering your question, as this is a very common pattern (and has nothing to do with profiles).